# React state hook variable is inconsistent with ui

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, state

I have a react application that uses state hook to track how many items in a list. When I remove items from the list the UI updates but the underlying array of elements still shows all elements. Here is a codesandbox demonstrating the issue.

```
// App.js

export default function App() {
  const handleRemoveRow = (i) => {
    console.log("state array: " + feesArray);
    console.log("index to remove: " + i);
    setFeesArray(
      feesArray.filter((_, index) => {
        console.log("filtering index: " + index);
        return index !== i;
      })
    );
  };

  const [feesArray, setFeesArray] = useState([
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={0} key={0} />,
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={1} key={1} />,
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={2} key={2} />
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>{feesArray}</ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
// ListItem.js

export default function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li>
      <IconButton
        onClick={() => {
          props.handleRemoveRow(props.index);
        }}
      >
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </li>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-leakey-zewrb?file=/src/App.js

If you try to remove items by clicking the 'x' you will see one row get removed but underlying array will stay at 3 items, also it will not allow any more items to be removed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `index` prop to ListItem statically, but using the relative index in the array when you try to remove an element.

So in the beginning, the `index` prop matches the index in the array:

```
[
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={0} key={0} />, // Array index 0
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={1} key={1} />, // Array index 1
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={2} key={2} /> // Array index 2
]
```

This is why you can remove it the first time. But let's say you remove index 1, your array will become:

```
[
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={0} key={0} />, // Array index 0
    <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} index={2} key={2} /> // Array index 1
]
```

Then if you try to remove the one with `index={2}`, it will try to find position 2 in the array, which doesn't exist anymore.

I'll assume you're trying to render dynamic data in an array. I'd advise you to keep the data separate from the rendering of ListItem components, like this:

```
  const [feesArray, setFeesArray] = useState([
    { value: "a" },
    { value: "b" },
    { value: "c" }
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {feesArray.map((fee, i) => (
          <ListItem handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow} key={i} index={i} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
```

Working codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-monad-cqqsh?file=/src/App.js:389-679